# Ultrabornological representation for the space of uniformly continuous functions?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, banach-spaces, limits-and-colimits, locally-convex-spaces

Let $\{\omega_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a non-empty set of increasing (not necessarily strictly) continuous functions preserving $0$.  Then, for each $i \in I$ define the space
$$
C_{\omega_i}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^d):=
\left\{
f \in (\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^d):\,
\|f\|_{\omega_i,\infty}<\infty
\right\} \mbox{ where }
\|f\|_{\omega_i,\infty}:= \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} (\omega_i(\|x\|)+1)^{-1}\|f(x)\|.
$$
Then this is a Banach space since the map $f \mapsto f (\omega_i(\|x\|)+1)$ is clearly an isometry with $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^d)$ for the sup-norm, and the maps between $C_{\omega_i}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $C_{\omega_j}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^d)$ can be defined similarly by rescaling analogously.  This makes $I$ into a poset with
$$
i\leq j \mbox{ if and only if } \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}\omega_i(\|x\|)
\leq \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}\omega_j(\|x\|).
$$
Thus, we can define the LCS colimit of this co-cone $\left\{C_{\omega_i}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^d)\right\}$.

---

Now for the question, if $\{\omega_i\}_i$ is taken to be the collection of *all* monotonically increasing and continuous functions identifying $0$ (i.e.: $\omega(0)=0$) then does $\operatorname{co-lim}_i C_{\omega_i}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^d)$  contain all uniformly continuous functions?

**Note:**  Here the colimit is in the LCS sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, I miss something, but the answer seems to be easy: If $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^d$ is continuous with $f(0)=0$ you can define the weight function $$\omega(r)=\sup\{\|f(x)\|: \|x\|\le r\}$$ which is obviously increasing with $\omega(0)=0$. Moreover, it is continuous at $r\ge 0$ because of the uniform continuity of $f$ on the compact set $\{x\in\mathbb R^n:\|x\|\le r+1\}$. Then $f\in C_\omega(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^d)$ holds. The extra assumption $f(0)=0$ can be removed by applying this to $\tilde f(x)=f(x)-f(0)$.

---

This shows that $C(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^d)$ is the co-limit of $\{C_\omega(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^d)\}$ in the category of vector spaces. Whether this holds in LCS is a different question.

Comment: You mean in the category of topological vector spaces?  In that case $C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^d)$ has compact-convergence topology or some (non-metrizable) final topology?

Also, are these examples where, $I$ is say countable and fully ordered (besides the space of functions of moderate growth?)

Comment: You wrote: *Does the co-limit contain all uniformly continuous functions?* -- This sounds very much like an algebraic question (where the co-limit is the union).

Comment: Ah, I see the issue; my error.  But I'm mostly looking in the LCS category (I made an edit to help clarify), I'm sorry abou the confusion

Comment: Note that a uniformly continuous function on a normed space has a linear growth, $\|f(x)\|\le a\|x\|+b$. So you don't need such a wide class of weights $\{\omega_i\}$. 0n the other hand, adding $1$ in the denominator in the definition of the norms means you do not care to much about being uniformly continuous or just continuous.